TabIndicator cannot stretche to fill the entire width of each tab in my TabLayout
i am implementing an android application using tabLayout . I add to my TabLayout tabIndicator property but the indicator does not fill the whole width of each tab . have tried many alternative but still got the same result. Here is the layout :
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_dash"
    tools:context=".ui.modules.espc.intrant.IntrantViewPagerFragment">

   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/mhealth_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewpager2"
        />
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_90sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/liensiteweb"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
Here is my class :
    class IntrantViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentIntrantViewPagerBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding= FragmentIntrantViewPagerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager =childFragmentManager
        val adapter= IntrantViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle)
        binding.viewpager2.adapter=adapter

        // Link TabLayout and ViewPager2 with TabLayoutMediator
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewpager2) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = when (position) {
                0 -> "En Attente"
                1 -> "En Livrée"
                else -> null
            }
        }.attach()

        binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                binding.viewpager2.currentItem=tab!!.position

                val indicatorDrawable = if (tab.position == 0) {
                    R.drawable.tab_indicator
                } else {
                    R.drawable.tab_indicator2
                }
                binding.tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(indicatorDrawable)

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

        })


        binding.viewpager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object:ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                binding.tabLayout.selectTab(binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(position))

            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                binding.viewpager2.isUserInputEnabled=false
            }
        })
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

}

How could I solve it ?
